# iOS Crash on Splash Screen on Return from Another App

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, appdelegate, square

My app opens up another app and crashes on the splash screen when the user returns to my app.

I haven't been able to replicate the issue and have gone through the debug logs to no avail so far. I think the crash relates to application:openURL:options in App Delegate.

Any ideas?

Here's my code for that method:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {

NSString *string = [options objectForKey:UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
if (string && [string hasPrefix:@"com.squareup.square"]) {

    PFObject *parseOrder = self.dataManager.parseOrderObject;
    if (parseOrder && url && options) {

        [self.dataExtraction squareUploadSuccessfulPaymentHelperWithParseOrder:parseOrder
                                                                           URL:url
                                                                       options:options];
    }
    return YES;
}
return NO;
```

}

Here are the logs:

> 

```html
Incident Identifier: 4506A316-557A-4E89-9A24-3A48AB167EE4
CrashReporter Key:   ba26439f76bc207f8db936b344220e545a0b368d
Hardware Model:      iPad5,4
Process:             APPNAME [974]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8810679A-29AB-41E1-8A9D-B08D1C68B72B/APPNAME.app/APPNAME
Identifier:          com.NAME.APPNAME
Version:             1 (1.47)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.NAME.APPNAME [815]


Date/Time:           2018-03-07 14:45:27.1669 -0500
Launch Time:         2018-03-07 14:45:26.2575 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x187a821c0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x1864bc55c objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                 0x187961600 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 311
3   CoreFoundation                 0x18796d38c +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 51
4   Parse                          0x10071823c 0x100690000 + 557628
5   APPNAME                        0x100149ae4 0x1000d4000 + 482020
6   APPNAME                        0x100148e64 0x1000d4000 + 478820
7   APPNAME                        0x10014827c 0x1000d4000 + 475772
8   APPNAME                        0x1001ab4fc 0x1000d4000 + 881916
9   UIKit                          0x18db663a4 __45-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:]_block_invoke + 751
10  UIKit                          0x18db65e30 -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:] + 655
11  UIKit                          0x18db58ba8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4371
12  UIKit                          0x18db5e5c8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1655
13  UIKit                          0x18db72e60 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3137 + 47
14  UIKit                          0x18db5b5ac -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 167
15  FrontBoardServices             0x1896298bc __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 35
16  FrontBoardServices             0x189629728 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 175
17  FrontBoardServices             0x189629ad0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 55
18  CoreFoundation                 0x187a30278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 23
19  CoreFoundation                 0x187a2fbc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
20  CoreFoundation                 0x187a2d7c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 803
21  CoreFoundation                 0x18795c048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
22  UIKit                          0x18d9412b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 607
23  UIKit                          0x18d93c034 UIApplicationMain + 207
24  APPNAME                        0x1001b809c 0x1000d4000 + 934044
25  libdyld.dylib                  0x1869405b8 start + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a52014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b1a450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00000001869c63e0 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001864912d4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001864aecc0 default_unexpected_handler+ 126144 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001864bc844 _objc_terminate+ 34884 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001864ab66c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 112236 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001864ab234 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001864bc71c objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018795c0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
10  UIKit                          0x000000018d9412b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 608
11  UIKit                          0x000000018d93c034 UIApplicationMain + 208
12  APPNAME                        0x00000001001b809c 0x1000d4000 + 934044
13  libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001869405b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a52a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b1635c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15da4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a52a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b1635c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15da4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15da0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a3416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a33fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187a2fcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187a2d908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018795c048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CFNetwork                      0x000000018814dfd0 +[NSURLConnection+ 847824 (Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6   Foundation                     0x000000018856b47c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b18850 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b18760 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15dac thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15da0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.parse.PFCommandCache.processing
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a51e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b179c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   Foundation                     0x00000001884be590 -[NSCondition wait] + 240
3   Bolts                          0x0000000100498218 0x100484000 + 82456
4   Parse                          0x0000000100698b1c 0x100690000 + 35612
5   Parse                          0x0000000100698ad4 0x100690000 + 35540
6   Parse                          0x00000001006cedc8 0x100690000 + 257480
7   Parse                          0x00000001006ce930 0x100690000 + 256304
8   Parse                          0x00000001006ce4d0 0x100690000 + 255184
9   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018690d1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018691a008 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576
11  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000186926648 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
12  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018690f164 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820
13  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018691b278 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 468
14  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001869109a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
15  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018691d38c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
16  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018691d0ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b162b8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15da4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a3416c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000186a33fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187a2fcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187a2d908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                 0x000000018795c048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                     0x000000018846da8c -[NSRunLoop+ 51852 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                     0x000000018848e57c -[NSRunLoop+ 185724 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                          0x000000018e2b6a2c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                     0x000000018856b47c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b18850 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b18760 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15dac thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15da0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000186b15da0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700f6437
    x4: 0x00000001864afbc3   x5: 0x000000016fd2b580   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x00000001869dd772  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001ac2cfc40  x21: 0x000000016fd2b580  x22: 0x00000001ac2d6bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x000000017001aad0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016fd2bbd8   fp: 0x000000016fd2b4e0   lr: 0x0000000186b1a450
    sp: 0x000000016fd2b4c0   pc: 0x0000000186a52014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Look up how to use "symbolicatecrash".  It will turn `5   APPNAME                        0x100149ae4 0x1000d4000 + 482020` into a code reference that should be more useful.  The actual problem seems to be 3 layers down from the method you posted.

Comment: @PhillipMills I did some digging on symbolicating crashes. Can I symbolicate a crash from a developer version of my app that's not on the app store (direct-to-device debug build)? I've had trouble finding how to do that.

Comment: Also, when you say 3 layers down, does that mean 3 methods deeper than squareUploadSuccessfulPaymentHelperWithParseOrder? As in the bug is within a helper called by another helper that that method calls. @PhillipMills

Comment: You can symbolicate a debug build if you still have the exact binary that crashed.  And, yes, `openURL` is probably the "+ 881916" entry on the stack.  It called something, which called something, which called something, which called "Parse".